# NavigationView menu's .add not working except in main bodies of onCreate() and onResume()

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer, menuitem

This is the code of `onNavigationItemSelcted`

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    Menu eventMenu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
    eventMenu.add(R.id.events,Menu.NONE,1,"newEvent").setIcon(R.drawable.hangouts_white);
    // extra code
}
```

However, I can perfectly use this add method in onCreate() and onResume(). But, again, if I use this method in onClick() in onCreate() or onResume(), it does not work. As long as it is in their main body, it will work.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   
    mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
 
    drawerAndToggle();//For drawerlayout setup
    
    Menu eventMenu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem eventItem = eventMenu.findItem(R.id.add_custom_event);
    eventItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // This gets executed but does not do anything
            eventMenu.add(R.id.events,Menu.NONE,1,"New item");
            return true;
        }
    });
    // This one works fine
    eventMenu.add(R.id.events,Menu.NONE,1,"New item");
}
```

But I need to add an item if the user selects "Add Item" which is one of the menu items in the Navigation Drawer. What am I missing or what should I be adding?

Here is my nav_menu XML of my navigation view

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:id="@+id/events">

        <item
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:title="Item 1" />
       
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:title="Item 2" />
    </group>
    
    <group android:id="@+id/settings">
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            android:id="@+id/add_item"
            android:title="Add Item"/>
    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: We need more info on what is `onClick()` when it's called?

Comment: I called it in a seperate case for trying alternative ways in making this work. I called onClick of menuItem in onCreate() and in onResume(). But outside the onClick() which is main body of onCreate and onResume, add method works just fine

Comment: Can you show this part of code that doesn't work including the `onClick()`

Comment: I updated. I am showing onCreate() here but same applies to onResume() too